# Twitter API request_token 401

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth, koa

I am having trouble obtaining an `oauth_token` from the Twitter API. I followed this [guide](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature) and read this [reference documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/request_token), but the response I always get is

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 32,
      "message": "Could not authenticate you."
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is all the code for my route with the keys replaced. Please if you can spot what is wrong with it I appreciate your help!

```
const setAccessToken = async (ctx) => {
  const httpMethod = 'post';
  const requestUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
  const callback = 'http://localhost:8080/twitter/callback';
  const consumerKey = 'foo';
  // generate a random ~32 byte nonce with only alphanumeric characters
  const nonce = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('base64').replace(/[^0-9a-z]/gi, '');
  const signatureMethod = 'HMAC-SHA1';
  const timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  const accessToken = 'bar';
  const version = '1.0';

  const parameterString = [
    `${encodeURIComponent('oauth_callback')}=${encodeURIComponent(callback)}`,
    `${encodeURIComponent('oauth_consumer_key')}=${encodeURIComponent(consumerKey)}`,
    `${encodeURIComponent('oauth_nonce')}=${encodeURIComponent(nonce)}`,
    `${encodeURIComponent('oauth_signature_method')}=${encodeURIComponent(signatureMethod)}`,
    `${encodeURIComponent('oauth_timestamp')}=${encodeURIComponent(timestamp)}`,
    `${encodeURIComponent('oauth_token')}=${encodeURIComponent(accessToken)}`,
    `${encodeURIComponent('oauth_version')}=${encodeURIComponent(version)}`,
  ].join('&');

  const signatureBaseString = [
    httpMethod.toUpperCase(),
    encodeURIComponent(requestUrl),
    encodeURIComponent(parameterString),
  ].join('&');

  const consumerSecret = 'fizz';
  const accessTokenSecret = '';

  const signingKey = [
    encodeURIComponent(consumerSecret),
    encodeURIComponent(accessTokenSecret),
  ].join('&');

  const signature = Buffer.from(crypto.createHmac('sha1', signingKey).update(signatureBaseString).digest('hex')).toString('base64');

  const headerSubstring = [
    `${encodeURIComponent('oauth_callback')}="${encodeURIComponent(callback)}"`,
    `${encodeURIComponent('oauth_consumer_key')}="${encodeURIComponent(consumerKey)}"`,
    `${encodeURIComponent('oauth_nonce')}="${encodeURIComponent(nonce)}"`,
    `${encodeURIComponent('oauth_signature')}="${encodeURIComponent(signature)}"`,
    `${encodeURIComponent('oauth_signature_method')}="${encodeURIComponent(signatureMethod)}"`,
    `${encodeURIComponent('oauth_timestamp')}="${encodeURIComponent(timestamp)}"`,
    `${encodeURIComponent('oauth_token')}="${encodeURIComponent(accessToken)}"`,
    `${encodeURIComponent('oauth_version')}="${encodeURIComponent(version)}"`,
  ].join(', ');

  const headerString = `OAuth ${headerSubstring}`;

  try {
    const { data } = await axios({
      headers: {
        Authorization: headerString,
      },
      method: httpMethod,
      url: requestUrl,
    });
    ctx.body = data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('e', e.response.data);
    console.log('e', e.response.status);
    console.log('e', e.response.headers);
    ctx.body = e.response.data;
  }
};
```